# Recovering a windows key from dead machine

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently my office laptop which was using windows 10 was replaced with a new one since it had an issue and the hard drive was swapped to the new one. Since then windows reports that my windows is not activated and when I try to activate it says it cannot activate. How can I activate the windows? The key is genuine.

Comment: Windows 10 was licensed to your old machine if it wasn't bought separately. In that case you can't transfer that license to your new computer.

Comment: Your **office laptop**? If this is not your own machine, then the office or IT staff are responsible for licensing. You should not be providing licenses for your office.

Comment: Actually the laptop is provided with linux but I had a spare key for windows 10 so I installed it on the laptop.

Answer (score -3):

It depends if there is a OEM key in the BIOS/UEFI the problem that occurs to you shouldn`t happen, if it had previously had windows 7 and you or the previous owner upgraded to 10 at the free upgrade could make problems because of the serial number of the windows 7 copy. I tried to be as helpful as i could because iam a GNU/Linux user. Good Luck !